# automatically convert list of pointers to derived class to list of pointers to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

Lets say that I have a base and derived class, and a function that takes an stl vector of pointers to the base class:

```
class A { public: int x; };

class B : public A { };

void foo(const vector<A*> &va) {
    for (vector<A*>::const_iterator it = va.begin(); it < va.end(); it++)
        cout << (*it)->x << endl;
}
```

is there any way to pass a list of pointers to the derived class? ie:

```
vector<B*> vb;
// ... add pointers to vb ...
foo(vb);
```

The above will cause the following compiler error:

```
error: could not convert ‘vb’ from ‘std::vector<B*>’ to ‘std::vector<A*>’
```

Even though B* is convertible to A*.

Finally, if there is a solution for plain pointers, will it work with boost shared pointers as well?

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector<B*> and std::vector<A*>` are technically unrelated. C++ does not allow what you want as such.

A way around...Why not have a `std::vector<Base*>` and insert into it `Derived` objects? That is the point of polymorphism, dynamic dispatch et al.

Answer (score 2):

You can create temporary vector of base pointers from vector of derived base pointers:

```
std::vector<B*> bv;
foo(std::vector<A*>(bv.begin(), bv.end()));
```

But this requires that foo accepts const reference not reference like in your example, and it is very inefficient, requires memory allocation and copying,

Other, preferred solution is to make your foo a function template:

```
template <class T>
void foo(std::vector<T*>& v);
```

To be sure that `foo` will be used only for A derived, use type_traits and SFINAE technique, note that you call `foo` only with first argument, the second is only for eliminating this function template for types not derived from A (SFINAE):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
void foo(std::vector<T*>& av,
         // don't use this second param 
         typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A,T>::value>::type* = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Science_Fiction said earlier, it makes more sense to have a vector that holds pointers to the basic type and insert pointers to both basic and derived types into it, but if you don't control the creation of these arrays, you can use templates:

```
template <class T>
inline void foo(const vector<T*>& v)
{
    for (vector<T*>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); ++it)
    {
        A* a = (A*) *it;
        cout << a->x << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: To make things more clear in my mind,this method will neither belong to `Base` class nor 'Derived` class right? I mean, the whole point of having templates is to have type independent programming. Isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a `vector<B*>` to `foo` because the types are incompatible -- it doesn't make a difference that `B*` is implicitly convertible to `A*`.

What you can do is create a new `vector` of the correct type, which is possible with, for example:

```
vector<B*> vb;
// ... add pointers to vb ...

vector<A*> va(vb.size());
std::transform(vb.begin(), vb.end(), va.begin(),
               [] (B* p) { return static_cast<A*>(p); });
```