# How to pass std::list of derived class instead of a std::list of parent class to a function?

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance, stdlist

Why is the second call to `print_all` function is causing a *static semantic error*?

```
#include <list>
using std::list;
class foo {
    // ...
};
class bar : public foo {
    // ...
};

static void print_all(list<foo*>& L) {
    // ...
}

list<foo*> LF;
list<bar*> LB;
// ...
print_all(LF); // works fine 
print_all(LB); // static semantic error
```

Comment: Relevant/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868347/automatically-convert-list-of-pointers-to-derived-class-to-list-of-pointers-to-b

Comment: @JeJo - My instinct as well. But I'm hesitant to use a binding vote here.

Comment: Another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849639/c-polymorphism-and-vectors-pointing-a-derived-class-of-vectors-to-a-base-clas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::list` is a template class, meaning, one needs to instantiated with a type, to get the full class definition for the required templated class. When the `std::list` has been instantiated with `foo` and `bar`, we get completely different types. That means the `bar` *is a* `foo`(due to the inheritance), but the  `std::list<foo*>` is different type than `std::list<bar*>`. Therefore, the `print_all(std::list<foo*> &L)` can only take the *list of pointers to `foo`* 's, as per the given definition.

The simplest solution to the problem is the [templated function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template). Make the `print_all` function templeted one, by which it can also accept other types(i.e. `std::list<foo*>`, `std::list<bar*>`, etc...) too.

```
template<typename Type>                   // --> template parameter
void print_all(std::list<Type*> const& L) // --> function parameter
//                              ^^^^^^ --------> use `const-ref` as the list is
//                                               not being modified inside the function
{ 
   // print the list   
}
```

However, that will now accept other types too, such as `std::list<int*>`, `std::list<float*>`, etc..(all other possible types). This might not be the behaviour you want. There we have so-called *["Substitution Failure Is Not An Error" (SFINAE)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)* technique, by which one can restrict the instantiation of the templated `print_all` function, if and only if, the template `Type` [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) the `foo` class. Something like

```
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if, std::is_base_of

template<typename T>
auto print_all(std::list<T*> const& L)-> std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<foo, T>> // in C++14
// or
// auto print_all(std::list<T*> const& L)-> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<foo, T>::value>::type // in C++11
{
    // print the list
}
```